# Dúvida no método de usar o Distinct e Count juntos!

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, count, distinct

Tenho uma tabela pedidos como a do exemplo abaixo:

```
 Id | Cliente | Status
 1  | XPTO    | Proposta
 2  | ABCD    | Proposta
 3  | XPTO    | Venceu
 4  | XPTO    | Perdeu
```

E quero apresentar um resultado assim:

```
Cliente | Status    | Qtd
XPTO    | Proposta  | 02
XPTO    | Venceu    | 01
ABCD    | Proposta  | 01
```

Já fiz algumas tentativas e não consegui nada!

O máximo que consegui foi o resultado abaixo no MySQL Workbrench, porém não consegui reproduzir o mesmo no meu código:

```
Status    | Qtd
Proposta  | 03
Venceu    | 01
```

Código executado no MySQL Workbrench:

```
SELECT distinct (status), count(cliente) as qtd_cliente 
FROM portal.pedidos 
group by status;
```

E como fazer isso no Laravel? Abaixo estou colocando o código do controller:

```
class RelatorioController extends Controller
{
    public function index ()
    {
        $relatorio = \App\Pedido::join('clientes', 'cliente', '=', 'nome')
        ->get();

        $cliente = \App\Cliente::lists('nome');

        return view ('relatorio.index',compact('relatorio','cliente'));
    }

    public function status()
    {

//o código abaixo é exatamente onde tenho dúvida, por isto o mesmo não está correto!!! Estas foram tentativas mal sucedidas dos meus testes.

        $status = \App\Pedido::distinct('status')           
            ->groupby('cliente')
            ->get();    

        return view ('relatorio.status', compact ('status'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que a pergunta tem a tag Laravel?

Comment: Se tiverem vários clientes que tiverem feito propostas, qual você quer exibir na coluna `Cliente` da resposta?

Comment: Se o problema é do lado do PHP poste o enxerto de código com problema.

Comment: Não vejo a necessidade de usar o distinct  uma vez que você já esta agrupando no seu group by status;

Comment: por acaso, em `4  | XPTO    | Perdeu` não seria `4  | XPTO    | Proposta`?

Comment: Para dar a pergunta como resolvida é só pressionar o V do lado da resposta certa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não precisa do `distinct`, o `group by` faz o serviço todo nesse caso:

```
SELECT cliente, status, count(cliente) as qtd_cliente 
FROM portal.pedidos 
group by cliente, status;
```

Se você usar `distinct(status)` como no seu exemplo, ele vai pegar os status sem repetir, omitindo os clientes.

Comment: Perfeito!!! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!
Você sabe como fazer isso no laravel???

Comment: @DanielAnselmodeAlmeida Infelizmente não sei mas deve ser bem fácil. Dá uma olhada no documentação do Eloquent Query Builder: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: Estou vendo que você é novo no Stack Overflow. Se você acha que a minha resposta resolveu o seu problema, por favor marque ela como 'Aceita' clicando no check verde dessa forma: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png  Valeu! Abraço!

Comment: consegui resolver o meu problema!!! 
Segue abaixo o código que funcionou...     

`$status = \App\Pedido::select('cliente', 'status', DB::raw('count(cliente) as qtd_cliente'))
        ->groupby('cliente','status')
        ->get();`